# How do I run commands that target a linux distro inside a mounted image?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to use Ubuntu Customization Kit, however it's failing because of a bug. It gets to the point where it mounts the necessary image, but then does not open the console for me to be able to customize it.

My question is, how can I manually open a console that targets the image instead of my root OS. I need to run **apt-get install** to install programs inside that image.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure but maybe "guestfish" could do what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to work inside .img files. In my case the image is already mounted as a folder within my tmp folder, so do you know any way to target a terminal to work on a linux distro located inside a folder, and have apt-get install install inside that distro ?

Comment: chroot comes to mind, see "failed backup" section for an example of getting into a second system by binding its folders then being able to apt-get on it - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery